# what's the explanation of progressbar lagging .. while the other progressbar works fine (both of them have the same code)?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, lag

i've two progressbar .. both of them have the same properties ..

when i start (sending..) one of them lags for a sec then continue like 45% then 53% .. but the other progressbar .. works fine with out lagging.

why does that happenes .. is there any explanation for that. i've also tried to delete the lagging pBar and copy past that working pBar .. but still the same.

here's the code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBarAll.Position = (int)((sumAll * 100) / sizeAll);
        ProgressBarAll.Text = ProgressBarAll.Position.ToString() + "%";
        progressBarFile.Position = (int)((sumAll * 100) / sizeAll);
        progressBarFile.Text = progressBarFile.Position.ToString() + "%";
    }
```

[image]

its really bothering me .. im so confused because they have the same code..

so how do i fix that.. thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using `custom control` for your progress bar?

Comment: yupp .. its xpProgressbar lib . i downloaded it from codeproject site

Comment: there is a section in codeproject where if you update the position in a tight loop or in CPU intensive are there is a chance isn't repainted, and you need to do `Application.DoEvent()`.

Comment: how do i use Application.DoEvent() to fix it .. can you post an answer!

Comment: I don't have visibility of the custom control code but I think it's a repaint problem. either override the onPaint method to implement like e.graphics.clear(this.backColor) to invalidate the drawing , or....to add 'Application.DoEvent()` in the event of ReportProgress (no guaranteed)

Comment: are you be able to resolve the problem? it is apparently the `xpProgressBar lib` you're using would "lags" on the drawing.

Comment: well .. im not sure about it .. i can't explore or edit that lib .. but it shouldn't lag .. i don't think that its about the lib .. i've studied about game graphics and the openGL lib .. and i worked some little project .. they take more drawing thousand times than a progressBar, it should never lag if we compare it to other graphics like games..

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that `sumAll` changes its value between setting `ProgressBarAll` and `progressBarFile`. That is because you are using `ProgressChanged` incorrectly.

What you need is something like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBarAll.Position = e.ProgressPercentage;
    progressBarAll.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
    progressBarFile.Position = e.ProgressPercentage;
    progressBarFile.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
}
```

and then call `ReportProgress` in your `DoWork` handler, like this:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progressPercentage);
```

Comment: i've already did that .. the same result .. one of them still lag for a second to catch the other one .. i think maybe it's a drawing issue ..

Comment: now i just redid that and makes it just like your code .. still the same.. specially when i maximize the size of the form the delay becomes clear .. the delay between the two pbar is about a second

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on the `progressBarFile.Text = ...` line. When you hit the breakpointt, both progressbar's positions have been set. Check to make sure they are equal. If they are, it could be a drawing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the issue here not around your progress bar - but rather, the processing / commands that the progress bar is tracking? I noticed one of your progress bar is called file progress; system I/O and disk read/write may not report back in linear time, or smoothly at all.

The question is, if it pauses and "lags" occassionally in disk i/o, is it really *wrong*?

Comment: i didn't get your point? what's about system I/O ?? as you see both of them have the same code.

Comment: Ah, right. Didn't read your question quite correctly...and you're certain the value of sizeall doesn't change between the sumall and sizeall assignments?

Comment: sizeall is the size of the file, sum is the sent bytes of sizall .. sizeall doesn't change .. the value is the same for both of them